# implementing graphs in php using google chart api

Tags: php, graph, visualization, google-visualization

i want a simple script/library by which i can draw simple graphs like line , column  , pie etc. 
No ajax , json , flash pls...
I have already tried pChart , amCharts  but facing some or the other problem in each... used google visualization api..found it good but unable to feed data to chart from my mysql database
my code goes as follows :

```
<?php 
include('dbconnect.php');
$sql_data = mysql_query("SELECT date , value FROM table1 WHERE   
                               value ='xyz' ORDER BY date DESC");
?> 
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <?php echo "<script type=text/javascript>";
    echo "google.load(\"visualization\", \"1\", {packages:[\"corechart\"]});";
    echo "google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);";
    echo "function drawChart() { ";
    echo "var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'Score'],";
    while($result = mysql_fetch_array($sql_data))
    {
    echo "[".$result['date'] .",".$result['value']."]";
    }
    echo " ]);";

    echo "var options = {
      title: 'Score  Analysis'
    };";

    echo "var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));";
    echo "chart.draw(data, options);";
  echo "}
</script>";

?>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Where exactly is it failing?  Are you getting js errors? PHP errors? MySQL errors?  Posting the client side source would help as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need a comma after each row of data except the last one.  Rather than echoing as you go, set the result to a variable...

```
$display .= "[".$result['date'] .",".$result['value']."],";
```

when loop is over chop off the trailing comma:

```
 $display .= substr($display, 0, -1);
```

then

```
echo $display;
```

See the playground for google charts:

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?type=visualization#line_chart

Comment: there's nothing else than a blank screen shown after making changes mentioned b you